# Third party payment gateway integration with Windows store App

Tags: windows-store-apps, payment-gateway, kiosk-mode

Is it possible to create a windows store app that integrate third party payment service through web integration (like PayPal or Authorize.Net) ?

Scenario is something like this. I want to create a windows store shopping cart application (more like a kiosk type) which uses third party payment gateway for payment transaction.

I want to utilize the Windows 8 ***Assigned Access*** feature. I am currently planning to do the payment operation by navigating into the payment gateway site with help of web authentication broker.

Is this the right way ? Please assist.

I have searched a lot in the net but couldn't find result regarding payment integration.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Third party payment methods are allowed in the store, but it's up to the developer to do the implementation. More information on the PayPal SDK for Windows can be found [on their developer portal](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/windows-8-checkout-sdk/gs_win8xo/).

When you make this into a kiosk app, make sure all the handling on the identity is very clear to the user and that he/she also knows what's being stored or when the information is cleared. This is clearly a trust-thing for the user!

Martin

Comment: "The PayPal Windows 8 SDK has been discontinued. There are no current plans to remove API support for deployed applications, but if you are developing a new integration, you should use another option such as a web integration." - Clearly mentioned in the specified link.